# Isabelle/ZF nat inequality

Tags: isabelle

I am new to Isabelle and I tried to prove something like this:

```
lemma refl_add_help: "[| n:nat; m:nat |] ==> 0 #+ n \<le> m #+ n" 
by(rule add_le_mono1, simp)

theorem mult_le_self: "[| 0 < m; n:nat; m:nat |] ==> n \<le> n #* m"
apply(case_tac m, auto)
apply(simp add: refl_add_help)
oops
```

I also tried to prove a lemma:

```
lemma "[| n:nat; m:nat |] ==> n \<le> m #+ n"
```

but I could not success either. Can anyone give me some advice on how to solve the problem? Thank you very much.

By the way, is it not possible to display value in ZF like

```
value "{m:nat. m < 5}"
```

I have imported the theory like this:

```
theory mytheory
imports ZF.Arith
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Isabelle/ZF. That said, you can prove your results as follows:

```
  theorem mult_le_self: "⟦ 0 < m; n:nat; m:nat ⟧ ⟹ n ≤ n #* m"
    apply (case_tac m, simp)
    apply (frule_tac ?m="n #* x" in refl_add_help)
    apply (auto simp add: add_commute)
    done

  lemma "⟦ n:nat; m:nat ⟧ ⟹ n ≤ m #+ n"
    by (frule refl_add_help, auto)
```

For more information regarding the `frule` and `frule_tac` methods please refer to *The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual*, sections 9.2 and 7.3 respectively. However, I encourage you to use Isabelle/Isar instead of proof scripts. For example, your lemma can be proven as follows:

```
lemma "⟦ n:nat; m:nat ⟧ ⟹ n ≤ m #+ n"
proof -
  assume "n:nat" and "m:nat"
  then show ?thesis using refl_add_help by simp
qed
```

Or, more compactly, as follows:

```
lemma
  assumes "n:nat" and "m:nat"
  shows "n ≤ m #+ n"
  using assms and refl_add_help by simp
```

Regarding the `value` command, I think it does not work in Isabelle/ZF.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me a lot. May I know how do you spot that it needs to use the frule? I understand that frule keeps the assumption comparing to drule. I got the natify if I use the drule, but why will it need the assumption?

Comment: @kaiboy05: In order for the simplifier to rewrite `natify(n)` to `n` by using the `natify_ident` lemma (see `Arith.thy`) you need the assumption `n:nat`, which is lost if you do not use `frule`.